# Observe property change of class instance

Tags: ios, swift

Given an instance of a class, how can I observe a property change?
For e.g., I'm building an SDK that initializes a host app's chat view to provide more functionality with a simple inplementation that looks like:

`sdk.initialize(chatView)`

In that initializing function, I need to track the host app's chat-view's `hidden` property so that the SDK's view matches.

Comment: `hidden` ? give more details, show some code

Comment: Do you mean that when the property in class "A" changes value that something happens in class "B"?

Comment: @Wain - `hidden` is a visibility boolean property on UIViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple KVO example for observing hidden:

```
class SDKViewController : UIViewController {
    private var context = 0
    private var observingView: UIView?

    func initialize(view: UIView) {
        removeObservations()

        observingView = view

        // start observing changes to hidden property of UIView
        observingView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: [.New], context: &context)
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? Bool where context == &self.context {
            print("hidden changed: \(newValue)")
        }
    }

    // this is called by deinit
    // it should also be called if they can deregister the view from your SDK
    func removeObservations() {
        if let view = observingView {
            view.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden")
            observingView = nil
        }
    }

    deinit {
        removeObservations()
    }
}
```

This is making some assumptions about your configuration, but if you allow initialization of many views, you can adjust easily.

Also, a lot of this is more concise if you use [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController) by Facebook, which is not in Swift.

Edit: Just to note, hidden **does** work with KVO.

Edit #2: Updated YourSDKClass to SDKViewController (NSObject -> UIViewController)

Comment: I'm excited.  This looks like just what I need.  However, I'm getting a "Value of type [Controller] has no member "context".

Comment: So I have an SDKViewController with a member function `initializeInputView` in which I'm passing in a UIView.
I want to be notified when the UIView's `hidden` property is changed from the host app.

Comment: Oh and I'll have to find a way to workaround the fact that the SDK class is a UIViewController already.  Adding NSObject gives me a multiple inheritance error.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Thank you.  It worked out fine.  I subclassed NSObject and simply made a UIView member that all the `self.view` calls addressed.  It didn't need to be a UIViewController subclass.

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew Great, just updated to subclass a UIViewController. Should be possible whichever route you choose!

Comment: What does `(NSObject -> UIViewController)` mean?

Comment: NM :-)  Also, I omitted `where context == &self.context` and it still worked.  What was its use?

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew It's a `void *` (generic pointer) that can used to pass some kind of "context" in order for an observer to differentiate between events in some way...in practice, it's almost always `NULL`. If you were using the target-selector pattern, for instance, you might register different selectors based on some criteria...all KVO 'observe' calls funnel through just this method, so it's an available (but ugly) means of differentiating. If that makes any sense...if not, just ignore it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using protocols

```
protocol MyClassDelegate:class {
    func myClassValueDidChange(newValue:Int)
}

class MyClass {

    weak var delegate:MyClassDelegate?
    var value = 0 {
        didSet {
            delegate?.myClassValueDidChange(value)
        }

    }
}


class ViewController:UIViewController,MyClassDelegate {

    let myClass = MyClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myClass.delegate = self
    }

    func myClassValueDidChange(newValue:Int) {
        //Do something
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key Value Observing (KVO) to monitor changes to general properties on classes, which includes the `hidden` property on `UIView` instances. This is done using `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` defined in the `NSKeyValueObserving` protocol.

Note that you can also hide a view by removing it from its superview or by setting its `alpha` to zero.

Comment: UIKit as a framework/module is not KVO-compliant. So that may work, or it may not. I haven't specifically tried to KVO `hidden`, but UIKit overall is hit-and-miss when it comes to KVO.

Comment: @ReidBelton - I can confirm that "hidden" is observable, at least as of iOS 10. However, as you point out, UIKit doesn't make any guarantees about KVO compliance, so this could potentially change in the future.